# running threads in background in c

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have created 5 threads using pthread_create. I want to run these threads in background, so I didn't join these threads. But the program is producing weird output. What can be reason for these?

Program:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, &i)

}
```

Comment: just want to know are  u managing the synchronization.

Comment: *`program is producing weird output`* ? what is output, What was expected? (read about atomic instruction and concurrency control mechanisms)

Comment: what output your program is producing and what were you expecting? Also please format and indent your code your question will be more readable.

Comment: Doesn't change question... it should match with answer

Comment: Please add to your question the output of your program and what you expected...

Comment: Can you please provide more complete example, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? For example, are you creating the threads from the `main` function? From another function? And what does the thread function `func` look like? And most importantly of all, what is the *expected* output and what is the *actual* output? If you don't add this your question will be closed very soon.

Comment: Are you setting the thread priorities correctly? You haven't given us enough info to work with.

Comment: You need to cast the last argument to a **void * ** and then cast it back to its normal type inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason may be that you pass a pointer to `i` as argument to the thread, and that pointer will be the same for all threads. So after the loop, `i` will be `5` for *all* threads.

---

Instead of passing a pointer, you can pass the actual value as a pointer, with the correct type-casting:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, (void *) i);
```

And in the thread function:

```
void *func(void *thread_argument)
{
    int i = (int) thread_argument;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Good guess!... probably that is the reason

Comment: Thanks Joachim, Apparently this was the problem.